# How is this a cyclyc copy?

Tags: windows-7, xcopy

In the following directory structure:

```
root/
    web/
        index.html
        etc...
    release_package/
        web/
        app.dll
```

I performed this command:

```
xcopy "./web/*.*" "./release_package/web/" /S /H /R /Y
```

And this was the result:

```
Cannot perform a cyclic copy
0 File(s) copied
```

That doesn't make any sense. Cyclic copy occurs when source contains the destination. This is definitely not the case.

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet it is because you have the slashes the wrong way and it therefore thinks you want to copy from the current folder to the current folder.

In windows systems, paths are expressed using a backslash rather than a forward slash.

Therefore, your command should be:

```
xcopy ".\web\*.*" ".\release_package\web\" /S /H /R /Y
```

Comment: hah, good catch. I guess I'm too tired...

Comment: @spikey_richie its great if you suggest an edit, but please don't change facts, especially if they're not entirely true. I've taken the few changes I approve and edited the post accordingly, leaving the unwanted ones unchanged.